# How to eliminate if-else when doing different things according to different combinations of boolean value?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

for example, suppose I need to do different things according to combinations of boolean values: cond_0,cond_1 and cond_2 :

```
cond_0 cond_1 cond_2
false  false  false  a();
false  false  true   b();
.
.
.
true   true   true   h();
```

it looks as if mapping bit numbers to functions:

```
000:a()
001:b()
.
.
.
111:h()
```

while the general rule looks like very simple, I don't know how to write it without if-else, and the current form looks like that:

```
var f=function(cond_0,cond_1,cond_2){
  if(!cond_0 && !cond_1 && !cond_2){
    a();
  }else if( cond_0 && !cond_1 && !cond_2)){
    b();
  }else if(!cond_0 &&  cond_1 && !cond_2)){
    c();
  }else if( cond_0 &&  cond_1 && !cond_2)){
    d();
  }else if(!cond_0 && !cond_1 &&  cond_2)){
    e();
  }else if( cond_0 && !cond_1 &&  cond_2)){
    f();
  }else if(!cond_0 &&  cond_1 &&  cond_2)){
  g();
  }else if( cond_0 &&  cond_1 &&  cond_2)){
    h();
  }
}
```

which is very long and hard to read. And when a new boolean condition cond_3 is added, it is horrible to modify the code:

```
if(!cond_0 && !cond_1 && !cond_2 && !cond_3){
    a();
  }else if( cond_0 && !cond_1 && !cond_2 !cond_3)){
    b();
  }
  .
  .
  .
```

Is there any way to eliminate the if else, so that cond_0 , cond_1 and cond_2 can just appear once only inside the function, and also easy to add new function when cond_3 is added? I want something like:

```
var f=function(cond_0,cond_1,cond_2){
  var magic=(000:a,001:b,010:c...);
  magic(cond_0,cond_1,cond_2)();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `true` to number is 1, `true * 2` is 2, etc.. probably something like this:

```js
function f(c0, c1, c2) { [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h][+c0 +c1 * 2 +c2 * 4](); }    // magic
```

Answer (score 4):

See this implementation. Here all the three parameters (boolean expected) are multiplied by their place values to form the number and then padded with `'0'` to the desired length. This value is searched for in the `magic` object and the function if defined is called.

```js
var a = function() {
  console.log('a() called');
};
var b = function() {
  console.log('b() called');
};
var c = function() {
  console.log('c() called');
};

var f = function(cond_0, cond_1, cond_2) {
  var cond = ((cond_0 * 100) + (cond_1 * 10) + (cond_2)).toString().padStart(3, '0');
  var magic = {
    '000': a,
    '001': b,
    '010': c
  };
  if (typeof magic[cond] === 'function') {
    magic[cond]();
  } else {
    console.log('No function defined for this cond');
  }
}

f(false, false, false);
f(false, false, true);
f(false, true, false);
f(true, false, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a bit of bitwise operations and binary literals as object keys:

```
function f(cond_0, cond_1, cond_2) {
  const magic = {
    0b000: a,
    0b001: b,
    0b010: c,
    0b011: d,
    0b100: e
    0b101: f,
    0b110: g,
    0b111: h,
  };
  return magic[cond_2 << 2 | cond_1 << 1 | cond_0 << 0]();
}
```

This object is essentially the same as the array literal in @Slai's answer, just with explicit indices.

It gets much crazier if you directly declare your functions as methods of the object instead of naming them individually:

```
const magic = {
  0b000() { console.log("a"); … },
  0b001() { console.log("b"); … },
  0b010() { console.log("c"); … },
  0b011() { console.log("d"); … },
  0b100() { console.log("e"); … },
  0b101() { console.log("f"); … },
  0b110() { console.log("g"); … },
  0b111() { console.log("h"); … },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea at the top. You can encode the functions in a map just like you put together conceptually by implicitly casting booleans to integers. Below is an implementation which can be easily extended to handle more states/functions.

```js
//initialization
var bitmap = {};
bitmap[0] = a;
bitmap[1] = b;
bitmap[10] = c;
bitmap[11] = d;
bitmap [110] = e;

var inputBools = [true, true, false];

pickFunction(inputBools);


function pickFunction(bools){
  var key = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < bools.length; i++){
    key += bools[bools.length-1-i]*Math.pow(10,i);
  }
  console.log(bitmap[key].call());
}

function a(){
  return "a";
}

function b(){
  return "b";
}

function c(){
  return "c";
}


function d(){
  return "d";
}

function e (){
   return "e";
 }
```

---

---

Answer (score 0):

> - I need to do different things according to combinations of boolean values
> - and also easy to add new function when cond_3 is added

There is no need to name them, just iterate over the set of arguments in the function.

```js
//range of preset functions styled as OP described
function a(){ console.log('a'); }
function b(){ console.log('b'); }
function c(){ console.log('c'); }
function d(){ console.log('d'); }
function e(){ console.log('e'); }
function f(){ console.log('f'); }
function g(){ console.log('g'); }
function h(){ console.log('h'); }
function i(){ console.log('i'); }
function j(){ console.log('j'); }
function k(){ console.log('k'); }
function l(){ console.log('l'); }
function m(){ console.log('m'); }

//This function will take the arguments, reduce their boolean value 
//to a 1 or 0 using |0, concatenate the string of 1's and 0's,
//parse out the string from binary to decimal, and then
//access the array's index correlating to the given decimal.
var truthTable = function(){
    var callers = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m];
    var tar = [].reduce.call(arguments,(p,c) => p+(c|0),"");
    callers[parseInt(tar,2)]();
};
truthTable (true,true,false);
truthTable (true,false,true);
truthTable (true,true);
truthTable (true,true,false,false);
```

As written, this will scale as far as it needs to provided that the decimal index of each function in callers correlates to its truth table value.

Answer (score -1):

Look at switches on mdn: `switch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: To actually make that useful, you'd also need to know how to combine the flags to produce a single value to switch on, e.g., bit shifting and oring to get `switch(case0 | (case1 << 1) | (case2 << 2))`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You aren't wrong, but its hard to tell if they're asking about boolean comparison operations or a more general if/then conditional type question. I'm erring on the side of more general.